# Auto logout is not working when switching account, problem is in ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5.8

I am very new in laravel. I have used javascript for auto logout functionality. The problem is when I am switching account that creates a problem. The scenario is as follows:

- Logged in as a Superadmin
- After login, there is a list of ServiceProvider. Clicking on it will impersonate them and the session data will be replaced to that service provider.

So now you are logged in as a service provider without logging out from the superadmin account. In this case, the ajax call showing 419 unknown status and reloading the page is logging out from that account.

I did search for that 419 unknown status but all of them are showing the same solution of passing the CSRF token. In my case, I am already passing it but still, it is showing the error only when I am switching the account.

Really need some solution on this. Thanks in advance.

Following is my auto logout code:

**layout/app-inside.blade.php**

```
<script>
var sesnLifeTime = 10 * 60;
var logtime = "{{strtotime(Session::get('logtime'))}}";
var lastActvTime = logtime;

$( "body" ).bind( "mousemove", function() {
    var date = moment.utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
    var stillUtc = moment.utc(date).toDate();
    var nowDateTime = moment(stillUtc).local().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
    var nowDateTimestamp = moment(nowDateTime).format("X");

    lastActvTime = nowDateTimestamp;
});

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {    
    setInterval(function(){
        var date = moment.utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
        var stillUtc = moment.utc(date).toDate();
        var nowDateTime = moment(stillUtc).local().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
        var nowDateTimestamp = moment(nowDateTime).format("X");

        var idleTime = parseInt(nowDateTimestamp) - parseInt(lastActvTime);

        if(idleTime >= sesnLifeTime)
        {
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
            console.clear();
            console.log("idleTime ==== "+idleTime);
        }
        else
        {
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                  'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                    url: '/dashboard.setTime',
                    type: 'POST',
                    async: false,
                    data:{'lastActvTime': nowDateTime},
                    success: function(response) {
                        console.log(response+"===="+idleTime);
                    }    
                });
        }
    }, 5000);
});
</script>
```

The above ajax is calling from the follwong controller.

**DashboardController**

```
function setTimeAjax(Request $request) {
        $lastActvTime = $request->lastActvTime;

        //== storing and fetching the updated time into session ==//
        $request->session()->put('logtime', $lastActvTime);        
        $data = $request->session()->all();        
        //== storing and fetching the updated time into session ==//

        $logtime = $data['logtime'];
        echo $logtime.'===='.$lastActvTime;        
    }
```

I am checking user activity every 5 seconds. So when I am switching account, instead of logging me out, it should be remain logged in as I am the active user.

Comment: I found that, every login that CSRF token is updated. So I also tried regenerating session while switching the account which leads to CSRF token to be updated but nothing happens.

Comment: have you tried putting in in your parameter instead of the header? data:{ "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}", ... } ?

Comment: Yes, I tried but showing the same error. If I change the method from POST to GET, the error is showing 401 unauthorised access.

Comment: i wonder why the csrf_token in you javascript did not updating. can you try putting your csrf_token in the input box and take it from there? someting like this `<input type="hidden" name="_token" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

Comment: while switching account if I regenerate the session then it is updating the csrf token but it is logging out saying 419 unknown status

Comment: Try putting csrf token like this `'X-CSRF-TOKEN': "{{ csrf_token() }}"`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I tried with it but nothing happens..what I am thinking is I am running this code on 5 seconds interval. Maybe this thing is conflicting while switching the account.

In the localhost, it is taking too much time to switch the account that is why it is showing such error but in the AWS server, this error is not showing as it is taking much less time to switch.